# Cannot use namespace 'JSX' as a value.ts(2708)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, theia

I am working on a theia glsp project using TypeScript and I'm trying to add a panel to my view,

Anyway, I try to render some `JSX` such as `React.Fragment` or `JsonForms` but I keep getting those
tags underlined with this error:

```
Cannot use namespace 'JSX' as a value.ts(2708)
```

do you have a clue about this issue